# Magento 2 - Limit reviews shown on product page

Tags: magento2, collection, review, pager, magento-2.0.7

I'm looking for some help with limiting the review list on the product page to 5 reviews at a time.
I'm using Magento 2.0.7 and Porto 2.2.1

I found some suggestions on here but they were for Magento 1.x and didn't help me. What I tried so far:

```
{theme}\Magento_Review\templates\product\view\list.phtml
```

changed:

```
$_items = $block->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();
```

to

```
$_items = $block->getReviewsCollection()->getItems()->setPageSize(5);
```

Result: **No reviews shown at all. Payed around but got either no reviews or 10 as usual.**

```
{theme}\Magento_Review\layout\review_product_lists.xml
```

changed:

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar"/>
```

to

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar">
    <argument name="setLimit" xsi:type="number">5</argument>
</block>
```

I also played around in the `pager.phtml` and even `pager.php` with similar changes but got no results. What did I miss?

**edit: Thanks, so far. Tried both changes, unfortunately I still get 10 reviews. Any chance that I need to change something somewhere else that I haven't noticed yet?**
Yes, cache was flushed, other changes were visible immediately.

**edit: I experimented with *application\magento\vendor\magento\module-theme\Block\Html\Pager.php* and found out that changing *$_availableLimit* or *$_limit* brings the desired results BUT that's not the clean way to work on this. Is there anything I missed? Is the class correct? Is the argument correct at all?**

Answer (score 3):

Your idea was good the order was wrong though.

Basically you have to change your first code:

```
$_items = $block->getReviewsCollection()->getItems()->setPageSize(5);
```

By:

```
$_items = $block->getReviewsCollection()->setPageSize(5)->getItems();
```

Regarding the pager, I think your syntax is wrong and instead of:

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar">
    <argument name="setLimit" xsi:type="number">5</argument>
</block>
```

It should be:

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar">
    <action method="setLimit">
        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="number">5</argument>
    </action>
</block>
```

Comment: Get out of my head :D

Comment: @fschmengler hahaha my cover is blown

Comment: I actually tried both before - and now again - yet the page always loads 10 reviews. And yes, I flushed the cache, other changes are shown.

Comment: I am trying to add pagination on my custom page , but the count is not working as expected , $pager->setLimit(36), how can I set it as dynamic  which we are filling in admin??

Comment: I have created custom module and removes the review tab ,and  Have displayed collection of customer reviews in new section in product page. Can you tell me where i need to put above code to limit the reviews

Comment: In whick phtml , I need to call this block  $_items = $block->getReviewsCollection()->setPageSize(5)->getItems();

Answer (score 3):

```
$_items = $block->getReviewsCollection()->getItems()->setPageSize(5);
```

cannot work because you first load the collection, then set the page size. You have to set the page size before it's loaded:

```
$_items = $block->getReviewsCollection()->setPageSize(5)->getItems();
```

**But this will not affect the pagination block and changing parameters using layout XML is the better approach anyway.**

The block might not understand your argument definition. Try `<action>` instead:

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar">
    <action method="setLimit">
        <argument name="limit" xsi:type="number">5</argument>
    </action>
</block>
```

Note, that `action` is deprecated and should only be used if `argument` is not possible:

> The `<action>` instruction is deprecated. If the method implementation
>   allows, use the `<argument>` for `<block>` or `<referenceBlock>` to access
>   block public API.

<sup>Source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_act</sup>

Comment: Get out my head :D

Comment: Thanks, the hint on devdocs about <action> being deprecated was the reason for me to believe <argument> alone would work. I had tried out <action> before and it didn't work. Unfortunately, I tried both your changes (even before) and it still loads 10 reviews.

Comment: Didn't work for me either.

Comment: @Torben, how can i add this to admin categories->design->layout xml update ... ?

Answer (score 2):

So far above solution didn't worked for me. What worked for me is to change this in core file `vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Pager.php`

```
protected $_availableLimit = [10 => 10, 20 => 20, 50 => 50];
protected $_availableLimit = [5 => 5, 10 => 10, 20 => 20, 50 => 50];
```

Obviously that isn't solution and not recommended to change in **CORE FILE** as it will be lost in update. Even extending this file in custom module will set this pager setting for whole site i believe.

**NOTE:** Just sharing it as it will help you go in right direction further.

Answer (score 1):

The way I got it to work in tandem with the toolbar/pager block (Magento 2.1.7):

```
$REVIEWS_PAGE_LIMIT = 4;
$reviewListToolbarBlock = $block->getChildBlock('toolbar');
$requested_page = $reviewListToolbarBlock->getRequest()->getParam($reviewListToolbarBlock->getPageVarName(), 1);
$reviewListToolbarBlock->setAvailableLimit([$REVIEWS_PAGE_LIMIT => $REVIEWS_PAGE_LIMIT]);
$reviewListToolbarBlock->setShowPerPage(false)->setShowAmounts(false)->setLimit($REVIEWS_PAGE_LIMIT)->setCollection($block->getReviewsCollection()->clear());
$_collection = $reviewListToolbarBlock->getCollection()->setCurPage($requested_page)->load()->addRateVotes();
$_items = $_collection->getItems();
```

In my experience I always have to clear() the collection prior to changing the page size and load() again afterwards.

Comment: clear() and load() worked

Answer (score 1):

For 2.4.* version I can suggest next solution:
Create plugin in the di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager">
    <plugin name="page_limit" type="YourVendorName\YourModuleName\Plugin\ItemsAvailableLimit" />
</type>
```

And in the ItemsAvailableLimit.php class add 'after' method for the getAvailableLimit:

```
public function afterGetAvailableLimit(\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager $subject, $result): array
{
    return [20 => 20, 30 => 30, 40 => 40, 50 => 50];
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for this question. This is the right way to increase the count for the reviews. Just one correction, need to add the condition for updating the pagination values for the review listing only. Currently, the updated pagination is working for all the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to get the above solutions working either, but I did manage to get this working based on some of the information given so credit to the asker and other answers.

Firstly my template was actually missing the pager itself, so make sure you add this into the product view layout;

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar">
```

The name is significant as well as it's mentioned explicitly in the `_prepareLayout` function `Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView` where the collection is also passed.

This created the toolbar but I wasn't able to change the limit in the xml. In order to do that I created a block which extends `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager`, set the limit using `$this->setLimit()` in a `_construct` function and it worked.